# MySQL to return single row per master ID with sub tables result in one column

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get the value from sub table **employment_types** that is relevant to the main table **hrms_emp_type** . sub table record can be multiple but when getting the result,
it should be like this:

```
salaryProcessID | description       
1360            | General
1397            | Consultant 
1557            | General, Trainee, Consultant  
1566            | General, Trainee
```

Link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1645/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT salaryProcessID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(description ORDER BY empType SEPARATOR ', ') AS description
FROM hrms_emp_type AS spTB
JOIN employment_types AS empType ON empType.id = spTB.empType
GROUP BY salaryProcessID
ORDER BY salaryProcessID;
```

**Output**

```
salaryProcessID description
1360            General
1397            Consultant
1557            General, Trainee, Consultant
1566            General, Trainee
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1645/24

**GROUP_CONCAT() function**

> MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function returns a string with concatenated
>   non-NULL value from a group.

**Syntax :**

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
         [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
             [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
         [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT
  salaryProcessID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(description) descr_list1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(description ORDER BY description SEPARATOR '; ') descr_list2
FROM hrms_emp_type AS spTB
JOIN employment_types AS empType ON empType.id = spTB.empType
GROUP BY salaryProcessID
ORDER BY salaryProcessID
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1645/16